# Play m4a in rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, m4a

I can't seem to get rhythmbox to recognize my m4as using newly installed 15.10.

I have the base, good, bad, ugly, and bad-multiverse plugins installed.

Have I missed a package or something?

Possibly relevant information: These files are copied from iTunes. Other Ubuntu programs play them though, so I don't think it's a problem with DRM.

Comment: Does it help if I say I don't have any problem?  Does your rhythmbox play any other formats?  I have also installed ubuntu-restricted-extras and audacity:  One of these may have loaded a library that you do not have.

Comment: Already install ubuntu-restricted-extras and audacity. I plays my other music (mostly flac, some mp3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an error with the install. I was having other random problems as well. After reinstalling everything is working.